# How to access django m2m self through model

Tags: django, has-many-through, self, m2m

This is my model:

```
class Store_product(models.Model):
    breakdown_lst = models.ManyToManyField('self',symmetrical=False,through='Kit_breakdown_assoc',related_name='kit_lst')

class Kit_breakdown_assoc(models.Model):
    kit = models.ForeignKey(Store_product,related_name='breakdown_assoc_lst')
    breakdown = models.ForeignKey(Store_product,related_name='kit_assoc_lst')
    qty = models.IntegerField()
```

What I want to do is:

```
sp = Store_product.objects.get(pk=sp_id)
sp.kit_breakdown_assoc_set.all() --> error: 'Store_product' object has no attribute 'kit_breakdown_assoc_set'
```

Django document mention a 'rule' that m2m with a 'self' does not add xxx_set attribute to the class. I think my case is just a special case of this 'rule' since it have an intermediate model. I found it is inconvenient that I can not access my through-related-manager. Do I miss something or this feature could be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, as you've correctly specified a related name, `breakdown_assoc_lst`, your intermediate model manager is not accessed by `sp.kit_breakdown_assoc_set`, but by `sp.breakdown_assoc_lst`, that is what you specify in related name.